# Is there a way to rotate and pan view while in knife tool and other tools that lock the view ports?

Tags: 3d-view, knife-tool

It seems there are many tools, such as the knife tool, that cause the viewports to lock up when you are "in" the tool. By "lock up" I mean that while in the tool I cannot rotate, pan, or zoom the view. This would be super handy and seems like a no-brainer. Thanks for your help!
-Ben

Comment: What is the problem to rotate / grab the view while in the Knife tool by pressing `MMB` / `Shift` + `MMB` ? You can also zoom as usual, by scrolling the wheel.

Comment: That's what I mean. I expect I SHOULD be able to do that, but I can't. I say the view locks up and the normal mouse navigation you are describing does not work as long as the tool is active.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is, as it works for me pretty well (versions 2.74 and 2.75 )

Comment: Wait, silly me... I've been using not a regular mouse but a 3D mouse (3Dconnexion) and got so used to it that I forgot I was doing it. I just tested with regular mouse and it IS working as I would expect. So I guess the issue is that this 3D mouse stops manipulating the view while the tool is active. I guess there's not likely a solution for that as it is a third-party issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I am using a 3Dconnexion 3D mouse and it does not manipulate my view while a tool is active. The normal mouse/keyboard ways of rotating etc do still work as expected while a tool is active.

Comment: I would [submit that as a bug](http://developer.blender.org/), you shouldn't have to switch to a normal mouse. 3dmouse support is programmed into blender so I expect the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am facing the same problem. However in my case it's related to the modelling settings I am using (industrial standard, with alt + left mouse button for tumbling). It's not possible to tumble while using the knife tool. I sincerly hope  this issue will be fixed in Blender 3.0 ;-)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/137299)